# Cut Sets in a graph

Tags: graph, theory

I have a question regarding the maximum flow in a network. I was trying to find a cut set in a graph that could disconnect the source and the destination. I explored all the edge independent paths in the graph from a source to the destination. Next I picked an edge from each of these paths and grouped them together. So basically I enumerated all the possible combinations of taking one edge from each path. 
So I have a set of such groups. Does this mean that I have eventually found the cut sets of the network for that particular source and destination? Is this an efficient method?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it has exponential complexity.  I can't say exactly, because I don't know what "all the edge independent paths" means.  For example:

```
   A
   |
   B
  / \
 C   D
  \ /
   E
```

There are two paths from A to E, but they're not edge independent.

A maximum flow on a graph is dual to a [minimum cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut), and there are plenty of standard algorithms that can find one in (small) polynomial time.  If you're satisfied with any cut at all, just remove all the edges -- this runs in time O(E).

What are your constraints?

Comment: Yeah! you are right about the exponential complexity. So I read on some other post that if I use the Ford Fulkerson algorithm, I can find the minimum cuts. How is it possible?

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that I need to find all the possible minimum  cuts in the network.